# Convert IObservable<Timestamped<T>> to IObservable<TimeInterval<T>>

Tags: .net, system.reactive

How can I convert an observable sequence of `Timestamped<T>` to a sequence of `TimeInterval<T>`where the interval is the time between the timestamps on the original sequence?

Given the input sequence..

```
new Timestamped<int>(1, DateTime.Parse("2000-01-01 00:00:01"))
new Timestamped<int>(2, DateTime.Parse("2000-01-01 00:00:05"))
new Timestamped<int>(3, DateTime.Parse("2000-01-01 00:01:04"))
```

.. the output would be:

```
new TimeInterval<int>(1, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"))
new TimeInterval<int>(2, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:04"))
new TimeInterval<int>(3, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:59"))
```

Comment: Is it required that the second sequence have the same number of entries? What behavior do you need for this implicit interval? (Also, is this structured such that you couldn't just call `originalSource.TimeInterval()`?)

Comment: Timestamps and values come from a log file, I'm looking to be able to replay them (at various speeds), I'd like to get relative times from the start of the sequence and schedule them that way.  The sequences should have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this does it.

```
var s = source.Publish().RefCount();
var sprev = s.Take(1).Concat(s);
var scurrent = s;

var converted = Observable.Zip(sprev, scurrent, (prev, current) =>
   new TimeInterval<int>(current.Value, current.Timestamp - prev.Timestamp));
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is if `Zip` ends when either sequence ends.  I assume it does, but I've not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a simple projection combined with `Do`:

```
static IObservable<TimeInterval<T>> ToTimeInterval<T>(
    this IObservable<Timestamped<T>> source)
{
    DateTimeOffset? previous = null;
    return source.Select(ts => 
        new
        {
            Timestamp = ts.Timestamp,
            Value = ts.Value,
            TimeSpan = previous.HasValue ? ts.Timestamp - previous
                                         : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
        })
        .Do(xx => { previous = xx.Timestamp; })
        .Select(xx => new TimeInterval<T>(xx.Value, xx.TimeSpan));
}
```

Used like:

```
var intervals = stampedData.ToTimeInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about observables, but could you do:

```
 myInputSequence.ToEnumerable().Select(t => 
    new TimeInterval<int>(
        t.Value,
        t.Value == 1 
            ? new TimeSpan(0) 
            : t.Timestamp - System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.ToEnumerable(myList).FirstOrDefault(t2 => t2.Value == t.Value - 1).Timestamp)
        ).ToObservable();
```

Of course this isn't efficient as possible, especially if you know the log statements come in order.